# Rails 4: How to overwrite constructor to return an existing record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a complex nested attributes system that I'll slim down to two models:

I have 2 models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products_colors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products_colors, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

class ProductsColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :color
```

What method would I have to overwrite so that when I'm on the products edit form with a nested products_colors form and I create a product + products_colors it first looks to see if a products_color with a certain `color_id` and `product_id` exists and returns that instead of a new `ProductsColor` instance?

The reason is that if there is a `ProductsColor` of `Product A` and `Color A` that already exists, I want to just update that one instead of creating a new `ProductsColor`.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
class ProductsColor < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  def self.new(args)
    pc = ProductsColor.where(color_id: args[:color_id], product_id: args[:product_id]).first_or_initialize
    pc.assign_attributes(args)
  end

end
```

Here's an example params submitted through the edit products form:

```
{"product"=>{"name"=>"zzzz", "products_colors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"color_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"24"}
```

I know it's a bit confusing... let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new method in Product something like `update_or_create_colors` that updates or creates new ProductColor, and in your controller just call that method, I don't thing there is a method in rails for your especific case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where you could submit a "color_ids" attribute (this is a dynamic attribute created by has_many

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products_colors
  has_many :colors, :through => :products_colors
```

This will build the join relationships for product and colors.